# Locating element in same paragraph of another element in watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir, browser-automation, watir-webdriver

Given the following HTML code snippet; after finding the link by ID, how would you select the checkbox in the same paragraph? 
For example if I wanted to select the checkbox associated with the link with ID="inst_17901-1746-1747".

The order of the paragraphs in the DIV **is not consistent** between sessions so I cannot select it by index or ID of the checkbox.

```
<div id="inst-results">
<p>
<input id="inst-results0-check" type="checkbox">
<a class="ws-rendered" id="inst_17901-1746-1747" title="!!QA Data 2/DOOR FURNITURE/316 Stainless - Altro Range"><img src="http://yr-qa-svr2/Agility/ACMSImages?type=objectType&amp;objectTypeID=32"> <span>!!QA Data 2/DOOR FURNITURE/316 Stainless - Altro Range</span></a>
</p>
<p>
<input id="inst-results1-check" type="checkbox"><a class="ws-rendered" id="inst_17882-1746-1747" title="!!QA Data/DOOR FURNITURE/316 Stainless - Altro Range"><img src="http://yr-qa-svr2/Agility/ACMSImages?type=objectType&amp;objectTypeID=32"> <span>!!QA Data/DOOR FURNITURE/316 Stainless - Altro Range</span></a>
</p>
</div>
```

I figured out this solution working off the text of the link, but Zeljko solution is much better.

```
    $browser.div(:id,"inst-results").ps.each { |para|
        if para.link.text == "!!QA Data/DOOR FURNITURE/316 Stainless - Altro Range" then
            para.checkbox.set
            break
        end
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is only one checkbox in the paragraph with the link:

```
browser.link(:id => "inst_17901-1746-1747").parent.checkbox.set
```

Works with watir-webdriver, not sure if it would work with other Watir gems.

Comment: Thanks, that should work as there should only be one checkbox per paragraph.

Comment: if there's more than one you'd need to specify a (how,what) for the checkbox.  which could be index if you didn't have anything better.  Although I suspect in that instance there would at least be associated text so the user knew what each checkbox did (instead of two naked checkboxes)